# Need Help in Receiving Data using TCP in Python

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi3

LED is not switching ON when I compare a received data with a char.

Here is my Code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
from time import sleep
import socket
from socket import *
from operator import eq

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(17,GPIO.OUT)

def led():
    IP="192.168.0.105"
    port=2525
    s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((IP,port))
    msg=s.recv(1024)
    print msg
    s.close()
    if eq(msg,'a'):
        GPIO.output(17,GPIO.HIGH)
    if eq(msg,'b'):
        GPIO.output(17,GPIO.LOW)
    else:
        print 'Pls Enter Valid Key'

while True:
    led()`
```

Comment: What does the code output? Try printing `repr(msg)`, so you can more easily detect if it contains trailing whitespace or a newline character.